# Question about extreme points of $L^1$

Tags: functional-analysis

The unit ball of $\ell^1$ has extreme points, but the unit ball of $L^1$ does not have extreme points. Also, $\ell^1$ can be isometrically embedded into $L^1$. Isn't this a contradiction, since isometric isomorphisms preserve extreme points?

Comment: might the notion of extreme points depend on the ambient linear space?
Just intuitively, when you take the picture in the wikipedia article concerning extreme points and expand it in a third dimension (so you'd get something like a deformed cylinder) the former extreme points need not be a extreme anymore , I tink.

But I might be off

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It had better not be a contradiction,  since it's true.

Yes, an isometric isomorphism preserves extreme points of the ball. The isometry $I:\ell^1\to L^1$ is not an isomorphism; in particular it's not surjective.

Say $X =  I(\ell^1)$. Say $B_X$ is the unit ball of $X$. Then $B_X$ has an extreme  point $p$: This says that $p$ is not a non-trivial convex combination of points of $B_X$. Nonethless $p$ *is* a nontrivial convex combination of other points of the unit ball of $L^1$.

Answer (score 1):

The embedding of $\ell^1$ into $\mathcal{L}^1$ is no isometric isomorphism, it is as you stated only an embedding.

Therefore, the extreme points are preserved with respect to the range of the embedding (since this actually is an isometric isomorphism) but not if you think of extreme points in the larger linear space $\mathcal{L}^1$ , I think.